# Connecting VueJS with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, frontend, backend, vue-component

Me and my co-worker both are freshers and I'm doing the front-end using VueJS and he is doing back-end using Laravel.

But How do we connect both back-end and front-end to deploy the final product?
We are struggling to put VueJS project files inside the laravel project files.

We don't have idea where to put `main.js`, where to put `routers.js` `store.js` `App.vue` inside the laravel

Comment: Did u see that site? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: this is working perfect check this and get idea http://laraveldaily.com/quick-start-laravel-5-5-vue-js-simple-crud-project/

Comment: Thanks you both =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Vue Js inside Laravel Project using npm,Then in your resource/assets foleder you will see the app.js, vue component.  Then compile it, laravel mix will place your app.js file inside public/js/app.js. Then include it in view file.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question when I start my career as a junior software engineer. Now I saw this again randomly. We had no idea how to connect back-end and the front-end. But eventually we learned we are developing a restAPI so we host back-end and front-end separately as two projects and connect them using the restAPI. Back-end and the front-end was two identical projects. =)